# Flutter app With azure notification Hub - platform android and iOS platform

Tags: flutter, azure, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

any one have best approach and any plugin suggestion for the Flutter app With azure notification Hub -  platform android and iOS platform

i done setup the azure platform
i done setup Firebase cloud message and configured server key with notification hub

and i followed the pub plugin
https://github.com/GhostBman/azure_notify_hub

the problem am not able to get register device and nothing happen

Then I follow the
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-flutter

from the above till the dart code part done . but that not working getting error
on flutter application on launch
getting  error

E/flutter (15740): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getLaunchAction on channel com.myorg.myapp/notificationaction

not sure have to complete the native code ( Configure the native Android project for push notifications) from the Link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-flutter

any one can suggest the best approach

Is there any other solution or approach to handle the notification

planning to trigger the notification from api backend node js code
if required i can register the device from backend node api code

any suggestion helpful

Comment: can you please share your findings, what works and best approach